# How to handle click event of BackBarButtonItem in nav bar using SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to handle an action when **navigation bar back button** is pressed. Yet I have set segue for it for another viewController.

Though I need to maintain a **count** when user clicks **5** times back button. For this I have implemented this stuff.

In this I've set an action for navigationbar backbutton:

```
class DetailViewController:UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.action = "perform"
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    func perform(){
        if count == 5{
            count=0
            print("Back Button pressed 5 times")
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Are you sure backBarButtonItem is not Nil?  Probably worth putting in a break point and making sure you haven't wired it up wrong.

Comment: Thanks now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "tapToBack")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

    func tapToBack() {
        var times = 0
        times++
        NSLog("tap times:%d", times)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it should be implemented:

```
override func viewDidLoad {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "back:")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
}

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  // your code
}
```