# Why does setting a custom backBarButtonItem for a UINavigationItem result in double back buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a very simple setup. A UINavigationController with a root UIViewController that modifies its navigation item with a custom back button item on `viewDidLoad`.

```swift
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backArrowImage,
                                     style: .plain,
                                     target: nil,
                                     action: nil)

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

I'm expecting this to completely replace the system back button with title *and* the default back arrow icon.

However when I push a new view controller on the stack, the navigation bar draws both the new custom back icon *and* the system back icon.

This is what I'm seeing:

[image: result]

This is what I would expect it to look like:

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to set global UINavigationBar appearance.
Apparently this has to be done at app launch.

```swift
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backArrowImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backArrowImage
```

With this approach we can preserve title animations and general back button behavior that would not be preserved if supplementing the back button with the `leftBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 2):

```
let backBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = .init(
        image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"),
        style: .plain,
        target: target,
        action: action
    )
    navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
    navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
    navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage()
```

This works for me, to setup custom "<" and hide the default one and still keep the backBarButtonItem behaviours

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the back button

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

and use `leftBarButtonItem` for custom `UIBarButtonItem`

#### UPD

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backArrowImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonPressed))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
    }

    @objc func backButtonPressed() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for because the `leftBarButtonItem` and `backBarButtonItem` are not interchangeable. 

The `backBarButtonItem` has a bunch of built in functionality such as animating with transitions and contextual navigation drop downs. If I use the `leftBarButtonItem` as a replacement it would just behave like a static button.

Comment: You can handle button click and call `pop` method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404421/how-to-handle-click-event-of-backbarbuttonitem-in-nav-bar-using-swift